# Getting error message oxc0000034 after booting up PC

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, windows-installation

I'm getting error message `oxc0000034` after booting up PC. I tried to install Win 7 and after installation got the above error code.

I tried to repair installation but still same the same error appearing.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Here lies your solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975484

Comment: If you just updated to any SP pack or any other update then I think you can restore your Windows.